# Multiple Raspberry pi acting as one

Tags: raspbian

My question is, can we setup multiple raspberry pi model b as one, if we take hadoop architecture, you will have one master and lot of slaves, but what I want is, connect like 4 raspberry pi's and they should act as one, like a single computer with 4gb ram, and 4 threads/cores since I have connected them as one.

Is there any way to achieve this, I have tried a lot but all I find is hadoop kind of architecture where you communicate them through your internal network and one is master and other is slave. SO, if there is a way to connect them together, we have to maintain only one hard disk for those right?

Comment: If not a master and slave where the master controls the communication and workload how do you expect this to work? You may want to search Raspberry Pi super computer or cluster computer but they all share a similar architecture.

Comment: the short answer is no, there is no way to do this.

Comment: +1 At no. In hadoop you split a task among resources to achieve said task, but you cannot connect all the cards and make it look like one.